# Stacks Clarity Smart Contracts with question mark

Tags: stack, blockchain, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

Why do some function have a question mark at the end? Like (map-get? ...)

I tried using without, but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Originally it was supposed to indicate that a response of some kind was returned by the function, but it does not apply consistently across functions. It's best thought of as just part of the function name.